# Issue with TFS 2017 Data Warehouse

Tags: tfs, warehouse

We have migrated our Team Foundation Server from 2013 to 2017 recently. In previous version there was no Data Warehouse or reporting configured.

After moving to TFS 2017, we configured Data Warehouse and Reporting services which went fine without any issue.

Now issue we are facing is, in reports we are not able to see any Build related data, only data we see is from old XAML build and nothing from new TFS 2017 build.

when I looked into DimBuild table of TFS Warehouse, it has only old data no new rows.

we tried to re-create warehouse and re-start TFS Warehouse services from Warehouse Administration link, but nothing is helping.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the data through [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) and do reports or you can get the data from collection database for reports.

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing it because it's not supposed to be there.

The data warehouse does not contain information for non-XAML builds, nor does it contain any release information.

Comment: Than what are the ways to create Build reports? Other then TFS dashboards.